# how to use autosizing in main view?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, frame, show-hide

Hi actually i am trying to find out a way by which i just escape from the useless coding of setting the frames when i hide the view or any other control on the self.view. All i need to  way by which if i hide one control on the screen the next control automatically take its frame. No more framing need to be set. Is there any way to do that? Guys i need your help.
Thanks in advance for help.

```
LabelName.hidden = yes;
```

LabelName is the name of my label which is going to be hidden.
[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: suppose i hide the second label named as Label 2. then the third label named as Label3 automatically come on the place of Label 2.  msgambel and  Pradhyuman Chavda Did you got it now or more detail should be provided.

Comment: if your all UILabel have dynamic y co-ordinate value than we can do it.

Comment: i just finding a way by which i need not to set the frame once again as i have described earlier.

Comment: Pradhyuman Chavda how can? please help

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer is **NO**, There is not any autosizing property or functionality that you want,

You have to write some code or logic to implement this.

Comment: this can be achieved in android apps so i m dam sure it can also be achieved in ios too.

Comment: @krishnabisht: this is **iOS** not an andriod. You have to write code for that.

Comment: Hi @Viruss mca I know that thing that's why i m asking. if it can be achieved in android so why not in iOS. iOS is so better technology than android.

Comment: Your thinking is wrong,it is not necessary that in android happen it should also happen into ios. both are different technology.